# problem with : in a link

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I posted a link on Travel.SE in

[Are there walking tours (where you join a group) in Rotterdam?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/18596/2521)

The link was as such:

> And more promisingly, [Gilde Rotterdam Guided Tours](http://www.rotterdam.nl/tekst:discover_the_city):

If you mouse over the link, the browser shows it correctly. However when you click it, it changes the `:` to a `%3a`, breaking the URL. I assume this is a SE-wide issue, so posting it here, rather than on meta.travel.SE.

On the other hand, if I'm doing something moronically wrong, let me know.

Comment: Considering `:` is actually a [reserved character](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2) in URLs, any site using them as an integral part of its page names -- and not checking for them being escaped properly -- should already expect to break all to hell.  But eh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's a fault of `rotterdam.nl` http server, not of SE. As `:` is a *reserved character*, [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) is not something messing the URL. It's because some web browsers can't process a URL with reserved character or even can be in danger of attack.

Comment: That's...awkward.  Any idea of a workaround I could edit into my answer - escape string or something, to allow for it?

Comment: @MarkMayo A possible workaround can be providing a shortlink like `bit.ly` instead, I think.

Comment: I was thinking about that as a possible backup, it just felt ... hacky ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo everything except fixing rotterdam.nl will be but a hack.